# How to get gRPC / protobuf version programmatically?

Tags: c++, grpc, protobuf-c

Is there an API to know gRPC/protobuf version or the git commit hash? We would like to include these in `--version` information of our C++ application.

The files `gRPC-Core.podspec`, `gRPC-C++.podspec`, `Protobuf-C++.podspec`etc. do have this information; wonder if the same can be extracted without having to parse these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gRPC exposes the version in its API:

[`const GRPCAPI char* grpc_version_string ( void )`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/grpc_8h.html#a1dd8f074f4417d3d775827fbc5ad0a4a)

For the C++ implementation there appears to be the following method in the `<grpcpp/grpcpp.h>` header:

[`std::string grpc::Version()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/165ee5007a77e4afbaa48cd9a32851b6799419ce/include/grpcpp/grpcpp.h#L66)

For **protobuf** the macro `GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION` is the integer value of its version & can be converted to string using the following API:

[`std::string google::protobuf::internal::VersionString(int version)`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h#L109)

Comment: thanks but I think this API gives the version string for gRPC core, it is from `src/core/lib/surface/version.cc`:

`const char* grpc_version_string(void) { return "10.0.0"; }`

I am looking for the version of c++ library of gRPC, e.g. for https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.30.2 I expect this to be 1.30.2

Comment: After looking through the templates I added the version exposed by `<grpcpp/grpcpp.h>`, which appears to be what you're looking for.